# React-router v4 nested routes & programmatic navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

So, I have a few routes set up in this fashion:

index.js

```
<Route exact path={pathDefault} component={Home}>
    <Route path={path1} component={component1}/>
    <Route path={path2} component={component2}/>
</Route>
```

component1.js

```
<Route exact path={`${props.match.url}`} component={Summary}/>
<Route path={`${props.match.url}`/someOtherPath1} component={SubComponent1}/>
<Route path={`${props.match.url}`/someOtherPath2} component={SubComponent2}/>
```

component2.js is set up similarly.

The idea here is that I have multiple top-level routes, which have default pages. But, then sub-routes that can be switched between. This works ok, until, when at one of the sub-level routes like `component1/someOtherPath2` I can switch between `someOtherPath1` and `someOtherPath2`, but if I then try to change one of the top level routes using `history.push(path2)`, instead of going back to a top level component (i.e. path1's default component), it ends up pushing a compounded, and thus incorrect route, like `component1/component2`.

So, how would you change a higher-level route when in a lower level component programmatically (preferably using `history.push` or similar)?

Comment: You can use `history.push` as long as you import history from whenever you inject it into your react-router. Once you import this into your component you can just use `history.push` like normal. Let me know if you get stuck and I'll create a sandbox for you.

Comment: What do you mean import it from when I inject it? You mean something like setting up `<BrowserHistory>`?

Comment: I should mention, I'm using `withRouter` on the components to get history on the props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history.push` takes **path** as an argument and not **component**:

*history.push(path, [state])*

for example:

```
history.push('/home');
```

or

```
history.push('/home', { some: 'state' });
```

you can read more about it in the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).

EDIT:

also don't forget the leading `/` if you want to change the root path. For example:

```
history.push('/path1/path2');
```

Comment: I'm handing the path to the component, which is the same name as the component. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: @Araymer when you want to change the root path are you starting with the `/`? Like `history.push('/path1/path2');`

Comment: I get an error when I try to add a slash on the front saying: 

`Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://path_to/classify_records' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000' and URL 'http://localhost:3000/path_to'.`

Comment: Ok, nevermind, that looked like the issue. For some reason, when I appended a single slash it was doubling the slash. That's a bug I can fix easily. But, it's working now. If you want to edit your answer, I can give you the points. There was just something wrong with my path building somewhere along the line.